# Installing MVC4 beta seems to have broken MVC3 apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the second time this has happened to me. I installed MVC4 earlier last year and had to go through and uninstall everything on my machine to get MVC3 apps working again.

When I realised MVC4 beta was available I reminded myself of this but decided to trust that it would work side by side again and proceeded to install it.

Now I'm getting the most bizarre error message in an MVC3 app.

I have a view that references a property on it's model.

e.g.

```
<td>@Model.NewProperty</td>
```

for some reason I get an error message saying that NewProperty doesn't exist. It clearly does and I know this is scoped to my machine as it builds on my collegues pc's.

If I comment out the @Model.NewProperty line it builds fine.

Has anyone experienced similar symptoms to this? It's strange!

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm eagerly waiting for the Visual Studio 11 beta the 29th of February.

Comment: Well that's good to know at least it's not just me! How frustrating!!

Comment: It turns out that this has nothing to do with installing MVC4. Somehow an old version of a dll managed to register itself into the GAC.

Comment: @TomMiller feel free to withdraw your question then.

Comment: @marcind sorry if this is obvious but where do I withdraw a question from?

Comment: @TomMiller I thought there's a way for you to delete your own question. But perhaps I was mistaken. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a related problem where MVC4 broke my MVC3 apps, they would not even compile. This is a known issue with the beta and the solution is here:

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

Look for the "Known Issues and Breaking Changes" section toward the bottom. then find "Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications"

It explains how to get your MVC3 apps working again.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Web.Config file and add

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
```

to

```
<appSettings>
```

node...